# Google Colab: TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float

Tags: python, opencv, readimage

I know there are similar questions and I have checked on that but it did not work. I try to open an image with cv2 in google colab using this code:

```
path='/content/group.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

But it was error.

[image]

I have checked on the image path and it is right. Can anyone please help me? Thank you :)

Comment: Can you show on which line does the error occur?

Comment: You define the `path` and don't use it. You should have `img = cv2.imread(path)`

Comment: Ah yes, pardon me. I tried many ways and ended copied that. I have edited my question. Thank you @aminrd

Comment: Hi @SamirAhmane I have edited my questions with a screenshoot. Can you please take a look? Than kyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in hand is related to the path of the image.

Your `cv2.imread` path and the `path` variable possibly point to different locations. Try locating the image you want in the file browser. If you then right click on it, you would get the ability to copy the path of the file. You must use that path to load the image and it would work.

```py
path='/content/group.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have tried that and it also gave error.

Comment: @mstd  Could you show what your error is?

Comment: Sure, it is said:
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float.

I have also edited my question

Comment: `plt.imshow(plt.imread(path))` please try using this

Comment: Ahh, I see. The problem is, the file is corrupt. I try another file and it works! Thank you!